# does setting enablessl=true in c# mean secured ftp

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ftp, ftpwebrequest

If we  just set EnableSsl=true in c# ftpWebrequest code, does this mean that a secured ftp is being done. Or else what is the right way to do a secured ftp in iis6.0. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

It means the request is sending `AUTH TLS`  command to the server and in case the FTP server does not support SSL it will throw exception.

So yes, if you don't get error it means that the data you send will be sent encrypted and it won't be possible to steal the data.

Information is taken from [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl.aspx).

Comment: okay thanks for the reply, one last question does iis6.0 support SSL?

Comment: Yes the SSL does not care what web server is used.

Comment: Here is the official guide for this: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/56bdf977-14f8-4867-9c51-34c346d48b04.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

EnableSsl=true this mean that you want to connect to FTP server that work on SSL protocol
 your FTP server should already be configured to work on SSL

Comment: okay thanks for the reply, one last question does iis6.0 support SSL?

Comment: look at this http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/56bdf977-14f8-4867-9c51-34c346d48b04.mspx?mfr=true